# Distribution histogram

Tags: matlab

Hi i am trying to make a simple distribution histogram using some code from stack overflow 
however i am unable to get it to work. i know that there are is a simple method for this using statistic toolbox but form a learning point of view i prefer a more explanatory code - can any one help me ?

```
%% 

clear all

load('Mini Project 1.mat')

% Set data to var2
data = var2; 

% Set the number of bins
nbins = 0:.8:8;

% Create a histogram plot of data sorted into (nbins) equally spaced bins
n = hist(data,nbins);

% Plot a bar chart with y values at each x value. 
% Notice that the length(x) and length(y) have to be same.
bar(nbins,n);

MEAN = mean(data);
STD = sqrt(mean((data - MEAN).^2)); % can also use the simple std(data)


f = (   1/(STD*sqrt(2*pi))   )  *  exp(-0.5*((nbins-MEAN)/STD).^2  );
f = f*sum(nbins)/sum(f);

hold on; 

% Plots a 2-D line plot(x,y) with the normal distribution, 
% c = color cyan , Width of line = 2
plot (data,f, 'c', 'LineWidth', 2);

xlabel('');
ylabel('Firmness of apples after one month of storage')
title('Histogram compared to normal distribution');

hold of
```

Comment: Update:  MATLAB's `histogram` command has a structured output that makes this much easier now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing

```
hist
```

with

```
histc
```

Read up on both.

Also, you are not defining the *number* of bins, you are defining the bins themselves .

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Matlab at hand now, but try the following:

If you want to compare a normal distribution to the bar plot `bar(nbins,n)`, you should first normalize it:

```
bar(nbins,n/sum(n))
```

See if this solves your problem.

If not, try also removing the line `f = f*sum(nbins)/sum(f);`.